# Lenovo U310 Wifi not working or very slow

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, lenovo-laptop, wifi-driver

Saturday 5th January 2013 My girlfriend bought herself a new notebook, with following specs:

Lenovo-IdeaPad-U310-Blue

```
3rd generation Intel® Core™ i7
Windows 7 Home Prenium
13.3″ HD 16:9 widescreen
1366×768 Anti-Glare display
Starting at 3.7 lbs.
Up to 7 hours’ battery life (Up to 90 days standby)
500GB HDD + 32GB SSD
4GB RAM
```

As a good boyfriend and IT specialist I wanted to help her setting up her new ultrabook.

Very Soon I noticed the wifi signal isn’t very strong and slow when connected and it seems te be a serious problem.

Throughout the tests I’ve seen a lot of drops and reconnection attempts, while being connected to the wifi.
The home internet connection has a 30Mbits WAN connection, these are the results from the new notebook:

```
1 to 5 meters from here wifi access-point: Max speed = 55KB/s
+ 5 meters = NO CONNECTION
```

with my 8 year old laptop (running linux)

```
1 to 5 meters from here wifi accespoint: max speed = 2MB/s
+ 5 meters = 500KB ~ 1MB/s
+ 10 meters = Max 500KB/s
```

After some research on the internet I came to the Lenovo Community Forum.
In this forum a lot of people where complaning for the same issue.
The only post from lenovo themselves was following:

> Hi.
>     Thanks for posting your findings, really appreciate it, may i know the manufacturing >date of your machine?
>      Previously the issues we had required users to send their machine in for a card replacement.
>    This issue only affects systems meeting the following criteria:
>
> - IdeaPad U410 manufactured on or before July 22, 2012
> - IdeaPad U310 manufactured on or before July 30, 2012
>
>   If the system meets the above criteria, check the wireless behavior using the following method:
>     If wireless throughput is slow, moving the system very close to the router will increase throughput to normal levels.  As the system is moved farther away from the router, throughput levels will begin to drop.  If the notebook is moved to a different room with a number of walls between the notebook and the router, throughput will drop to very low speeds

But later on people didn’t respond to this possible solution, did it help?

Possible solution I’ve tried already:

```
Driver updates
Driver remove and reinstall
BIOS update
```

For so far no solution except for a mini usb wifi adapter.
But I want to keep this solution as PLAN Z, I want it to be fixed cause my girlfriend payed for it (700€)

This evening I’m going back to the store where she bought it.
But the store is known for non refunding terms.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked to assure any antenna cables are properly connected to the card? Is the router B/G/N? If so, does it use all three?

Comment: I Can't open the case of this laptop, I will break the license so I can't take a look inside the notebook, router is dual band B/G/N linksys E2000

Comment: Did you tried to change the WiFi channel? Or detect what channels are used by the nearby Wifi networks?

Comment: Hi, It's single house on the full street :)
also other laptops (including an 8 year old laptop) are performing better. even when sitting next to the router the performance is very slow, it's a problem known to a lot of users (as seen in community of lenovo) but I posted it here hoping someone in here bought it aswell and had a solution for this issue.

Comment: Or had luck by sending the unit back, cause there were users who sended their unit back where lenovo claimed they changed the card but made it even worse or didn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case my labtop wifi slow down from 10m to 4m.

I found solution to solve by

1. uninstall wifi driver at device manager with (no checkbox delete the driver)
2. rescan hardware your wifi driver will appear again.

that magic my wifi speed test up to 10m like lan pc.

credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tzA6dkLk88

Answer (score -1):

I recommend taking off these plastic pieces. I don´t undertand why but it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what the hell? you have GOT to explain how this will work. No way the engineers designed it for that.